Injuries inflicted to Tyrannosaurus by Triceratops
I encountered this YouTube video:
YouTube video by ExtinctZoo
The video presents Triceratops as the only dinosaur documented to injure a Tyrannosaurus (excluding other T. rex individuals). Specifically, the following section mentions two fossils of Tyrannosaurus with signs of injuries probably inflicted by Triceratops.

The Dueling Dinosaurs: the famous fossil shows a juvenile T. rex with jaw injuries among others next to a Triceratops with a bite mark. This probably indicates that the two fought with the Triceratops inflicting more damage. It is unknown what has killed both.
A T. rex skeleton nicknamed "rex" (?) of a 12-meter individual with a puncture injury in its femur, where the hole matches a ceratopsid horn, with the major candidates are Triceratops, Torosaurus, Ojoceratops with Triceratops being the most likely one (because it was the most abundant large dinosaur of its habitat).

However, I could not find paper references to these fossils with the description of the T. rex injuries and the association of them to Triceratops' attacks. Do you know on which papers the movie maker is based and if there are, in addition to the full texts, open access or articles in popular science online magazines which I can refer to and indeed assert the injuries to Triceratops attacks.

I will start with the dueling dinosaurs specimen in which a Nanotyrannus lancensis (BHI 6437) and unnamed Chasmosaurine ceratopsian  were found together with good evidence for dying together. Not a triceratops but early description was of a triceratops so the confusion is reasonable.
The specimen has a strange and legally problematic history going through both private and public hands so published study has been non-existant. The hope is with their new public home more work will be done. Scientists don't like to publish on private specimens since access is not guaranteed so many publishers will not accept such work. On top of that a lot of paleontology publications wait until the yearly Society of Vertebrate Paleontology convention each year; with the grand opening in April of 2024, I do not expect much publication until the fall.
Hopefully it is real specimen, possible fakes is one the big risks with private collections and another reason it is strongly discouraged. If it is real it will represent a truly amazing find, but with no publication, ascertaining the truth of the injuries is impossible.
the lack of publication is also the reason for the lack of pictures "poaching"  publication occasionally happens so don't expect many detailed images until it gets published. This can even happen accidentally with new species because the first name given in publication is the one that sticks. So it is common for researchers to be protective of diagnostic images until the first publication.
https://www.bonhams.com/auction/21076/lot/1032/dueling-dinosaurs/
https://web.archive.org/web/20201117124307/https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/2020/11/dueling-dinosaurs-fossil-finally-set-to-reveal-secrets/
current location https://naturalsciences.org/exhibits/permanent-exhibits/dueling-dinosaurs
I know of no T-rex specimen named "rex" nor of one with a punctured femur, nor could I find any publication of either. So it is either not a T-rex or is not published yet.

Thank you for your answer. I'll wait someone with more information will comment.
